# Pass form data to another page with php

Tags: php, forms

I have a form on my homepage and when it is submitted, it takes users to another page on my site. I want to pass the form data entered to the next page, with something like:

```
<?php echo $email; ?>
```

Where `$email` is the email address the user entered into the form. How exactly do I accomplish this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: You can use serialize.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The best way to accomplish that is to use POST which is a method of Hypertext Transfer Protocol https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

**index.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="site2.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**site2.php**

```
 <html>
 <body>

 Hello <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>!<br>
 Your mail is <?php echo $_POST["mail"]; ?>.

 </body>
 </html>
```

**output**

Hello "name" !

Your email is "whatyou@addedonindex.com" .

Comment: I am posting the data into html code on the page, not plain text like that, does it matter? (I have an iframe on site2.php and I am passing the info to the iframe URL).

Comment: No, doesn't matter, where you POST it. It can be text, table, button, paragraph etc...

Comment: if i want to load site2.php content in dialog box then how can i do that. i refered [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960619/load-external-php-file-in-jquery-modal-dialog-onclick)

Comment: @Stepo there are any other way available for transfer data ?

Comment: This is what I wanted to find. Thank you. This works !

Comment: Anyone did get some CORS warnings?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_POST["mail"]; ?>.
<?php echo $_POST["mail"]; ?>missing syntax
<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>right $_POST["email"];
```

Comment: It should be <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>. There is no form object called "mail". All of the rest of the examples on this page are wrong too.