# Generate new page on form submit that display value from database

Tags: php, html

it's my first time asking a question here. (sorry if my english is not that great)
I'm not good in php and html. until last month I had never code html or php.
I'm curently a trainee for a company and they want me do build an intranet. For now everything works fine i have build a good site using wordpress but now they ask me for something too complicated for me and no one can help me there so i ask to you guys.

On my page i have a form that on submit lookup in an external database to then display them on the same page. Everything works fine. What I want is when user enter the input value, i want a new page to be generated. For now, when user enter value, the url stays the same (ex: http://localhost/vendors/), but what i want is when user enter ABCD, i want the url to now be http://localhost/vendors/abcd so we can share that link with the correct data displayed on the page.

Ive tried to find an answer on the internet but failed. Ive read that i have to use a template to generate the new page with the input value using the template but i have no idea how to do that. I also want the form to stay on the page, so we can continue to search in the database and display other data

Here what i have for now (I've removed all the useless things for the question):

```
    <!--Connection to mssql database-->
<?php
  try {
    $hostname = "hostname";
    $port = 1433;
    $dbname = "databasename";
    $username = "username";
    $pw = "password";
    $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }





/**
 * Template Name: Vendors
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package vantage
 * @since vantage 1.0
 * @license GPL 2.0
 */

get_header(); ?>






<form action="" method="post">
<table id= "formvendor">
<tr><td><b>Vendor ID: </b></td><td><input type="text" name="vendorid"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Vendor name: </b></td><td><input type="text" name="vendname"></b></td></tr>
<input type="submit" 
       style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"
       tabindex="-1" />
</form>



<? 
$vendorid = $_POST["vendorid"];
$vendname = $_POST['vendname'];

$vendorid=ltrim($vendorid);
$vendorid=rtrim($vendorid);
$vendname=ltrim($vendname);
$vendname=rtrim($vendname);


$query="SELECT ... FROM uni.dbo.pm00200 where ";

if(strlen($vendorid)>0){ 

$query .=" vendorid='$vendorid' or";
if(strlen($vendname)>0){ }
else{
$query=substr($query,0,(strLen($query)-3));


}
}


if(strlen($vendname)>0){ 
$kt2=split(" ",$vendname);//Breaking the string to array of words
// Now let us generate the sql 
while(list($key,$val)=each($kt2)){
if($val<>" " and strlen($val) > 0){$query .= " vendname like '%$val%' or ";}

            }// end of while
$query=substr($query,0,(strLen($query)-3));
// this will remove the last or from the string. 
         // end of if else based on type value
}



foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $t) {
echo "<table id='tablevendors' style='width:100%' cellpadding='-5px'>";
echo '<col width="40%"><col width="60%"';
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>Vendor ID :</b></td><td> $t[vendorid]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>Vendor name:</b></td><td> $t[vendname]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>Vendor class:</b></td><td> $t[vndclsid]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>Address 1:</b></td><td> $t[address1]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>Address 2:</b></td><td> $t[address2]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>Address 3:</b></td><td> $t[address3]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>City:</b></td><td> $t[city]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>State:</b></td><td> $t[state]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>Zipcode:</b></td><td> $t[zipcode]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>Payment:</b></td><td> $t[pymtrmid]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>Buyer:</b></td><td> $t[buyer]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>Minimum order:</b></td><td> $t[minorder]</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<td><b>Prepaid info:</b></td><td> $t[prepaid]</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}


unset($dbh); unset($stmt);

?>




//rest of template
<div id="primary" class="content-area">

    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                    <div class="entry-main">

                        <?php do_action('vantage_entry_main_top') ?>

                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">→</span>', 'vantage' ) ); ?>
                            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'vantage' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                        <?php do_action('vantage_entry_main_bottom') ?>

                    </div>

                </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

                <?php if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) : ?>
                    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

</div><!-- #primary .content-area -->
    </div><!-- #content .site-content -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Check out this stack overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236733/pass-form-data-to-another-page-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cobstyle.

The solution, as I see it, depends on wether you want the user input to be showed on the page address or not. If you want that, the problem isn't that hard:

**index.php:**

```
...
<form action="receiver.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="txtUserInput" name="txtUserInput" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Send!" />
</form>
```

**receiver.php:**

```
<?php
$userInput = "";
if (isset($_POST["txtUserInput"]))
{
    $userInput = $_POST["txtUserInput"];
    header("Location: show.php?msg=".$userInput."");    //This will redirect your page to another called show.php, with a variable on it
}
else
{
    header("Location: error.php");   //Show some error, just in case
}
?>
```

**show.php:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["msg"]))
{
    echo "<h2>User message: ".$_GET["msg"]."</h2>";   //This will print something on the page
}
?>
```

I hope you find this useful, though I believe it can be improved a lot.
Good luck with your works, and let us know if you need more help.

Comment: But with that, will we be able to share the new page to other people like http://localhost/vendors/ABCD ?

Comment: You will be able to share it as localhost/vendors.php?msg=ABCD, for example. I hope it's useful.

Comment: Glad I could help, @cobstyle. I hope you learned and keep doing it ;) BTW, please mark my answer as useful with the upper arrow on the left. Thanks!