# POST and GET are unable to display user input values from HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

I have just started to learn HTML and PHP, but have run into a road block while following beginner tutorials.  I am attempting to have the user input numbers into a form on the HTML page, then press submit to redirect to a PHP page that displays the values.  The PHP page shows up and successfully displays prepared text but displays nothing for the values.

HTML code:

```html
<html>
<body>
 <head>
  <title>Practice Page</title>
 </head>

 <h1>Numbers</h1>
 <p>Put numbers in the boxes</p>
 <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
  NumOne: <input type="text" name="oynumone"><br>
  NumTwo: <input type="text" name="oynumtwo"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitRegister" name="submit" />
 </form>

</body>
<html>
```

PHP code:

```html
<html>
<body>
 
 Number one is <?php echo $_POST["oynumone"]; ?><br>
 Number two is <?php echo $_POST["oynumtwo"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Both of the files are simply in the same folder in my documents.  I understand that I need a server to host PHP content; I have downloaded MAMP for this, but I don't yet understand how to use it.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: which OS you are using. Note - XAMPP for Windows and Linux, Lamp for Linux, MAMP for MacOs

Comment: Any error showing? try after adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in php file

Comment: try to add this in htaccess `php_value post_max_size 60M
php_value upload_max_filesize 60M`

Comment: I am on Windows 7.  Does MAMP not work for that, or not as good as XAMPP?

Comment: MAMP is  - Mac Apache Mysql PHP and WAMP is - Windows Apache Mysql PHP and XAMPP - X-Any Os A-Apache M-MySql P-PHP p-Perl

Comment: Yep, looks like this was part of the problem.  Switched to XAMPP and now I've got it running.  Thanks fellas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store both file name with `.php` extension **AND/OR** update Welcome.php like below -

Welcome.php

```
<?php
    if isset($_POST['submit'])
        {
            $oynumone = $_POST['oynumone'];
            $oynumtwo = $_POST['oynumtwo'];

            echo "Number one is ".$oynumone; 
            echo "Number two is ".$oynumtwo;
        }

    ?>
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236733/pass-form-data-to-another-page-with-php)

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to be part of the problem (changed both files to .php).  Also, I swapped to XAMPP and followed instructions for running files through its Apache server, which finally allowed the PHP code to execute (previously, I was simply opening the files directly with chrome instead of using http://localhost/filename.php).

Thanks again.