# How to collect and manipulate data in HTML using <form>

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm using  to collect data from users on a website. The question is, how can I collect and manipulate that code, and say, relay it back to the user? Here's a sample of my code:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
<h3>WHAT IS THE RETURN DATE?</h3><br>
<input type="date" name="HOTEL NAME" value="">
<br>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236733/pass-form-data-to-another-page-with-php

Comment: Is there any way I can do it without PHP, all through HTML? Also, is it possible to use that information to search other websites?

Comment: You can use javascript https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/Rgzapb. I don't know what you mean by "to search other websites"

Answer (score 0):

Use method "get" or "post"

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
<h3>WHAT IS THE RETURN DATE?</h3><br>
<input type="date" name="hotel_name" value="">
<br>
</form>
```

And in the "action_page.php" you can use this code

```
$return_date = $_POST['hotel_name'] ;
```

In this way you can store the date in variable $return_date