# Calling PHP and dialog box on one click together

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form where I want to show user their input data in dialog box and to save in SQL using PHP in one click only. Problem is I can call only one (either dialog box or PHP) at one time. As dialog box requires `anchor` tag

```
<a href="#" value="Save" onclick="submit()">Save</a>
<script>
    document.forms["myform"].reset();
    $(function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen:false,
            modal:true,
            width:400,
            height:300,
            buttons:{
                "OK": function(){
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        alert("Saved");

                    },
                "Cancel":function(){
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
            }
        });

    });
    function submit(){
        $("#location").html($("#pac-input").val());
        $("#type").html($("input:radio[name='sex']:checked").val());
        $("#open").html($("#open").val());
        $("#close").html($("#close").val());
        $("#review").html($("#review").val());
        $("#rating").html($("input:radio[name='rating']:checked").val());
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        }
    </script>
```

and PHP requires submit button to store the values

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<?php
            $address= $_POST['address'];
            $type = $_POST['sex'];
            $open = $_POST['open'];
            $close = $_POST['close'];
            $review = $_POST['review'];
            $rating = $_POST['rating'];
            $dbname = "addtoilet";
            // Create connection
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root","",$dbname);

            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } else{
            echo "Connected successfully";
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO add (address, type, open, close)
                VALUES ('$address', '$type', '$open', '$close')";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }

            mysqli_close($conn);
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: referred [load external file question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960619/load-external-php-file-in-jquery-modal-dialog-onclick). It worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Write the submit function inside the ok function of dialog.

```
<a href="#" value="Save" onclick="submit()">Save</a>
<script>
document.forms["myform"].reset();
$(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        modal:true,
        width:400,
        height:300,
        buttons:{
            "OK": function(){
                    $("#your_form_id").submit();// also you can call ajax here if you don't want to reload the page
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    alert("Saved");

                },
            "Cancel":function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
        }
    });

});
function submit(){
    $("#location").html($("#pac-input").val());
    $("#type").html($("input:radio[name='sex']:checked").val());
    $("#open").html($("#open").val());
    $("#close").html($("#close").val());
    $("#review").html($("#review").val());
    $("#rating").html($("input:radio[name='rating']:checked").val());
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i want to pass data to sql using php how can i run php?

Comment: give the form action url or ajax url to your php file where you have written the code in php. When your form will submit the php script will run

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Jquery ajax . which will post the data to the php on the same click. You can also use a shorthand method POST. 
Save the data you want to post in json format in a variable say data and pass it to post method .

function submit(){
var location= $("#pac-input").val();
 var data = "{ 'location' : '"+location +"'}";
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", data,function() {
 console.log( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
$("#dialog").dialog("open");

})
  .fail(function() {
 console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
 console.log( "finished" );
});

}
You can open the dialog depending on the success of the post method

Comment: what does example.php means??

Comment: It is the php file that receives the data using POST method from the client side.

Comment: i.e the name of the file that contents php script :

Comment: Your data variable would store the following 

data =  "{'address':'"+$("#pac-input").val()+"','sex':'"+$("input:radio[name='sex']:checked").val()+"' ,'open':'"+$("#open").val()+"','close':'"+$("#close").val()+"','review':'"+$("#review").val()+"','rating':'"+$("input:radio[name='rating']:checked").val()+"'}"